# How to set DI of service di in micro phalcon application? When setting DI with services is not working, how to handle that application?

Tags: php, phalcon

How to set DI of service di in micro phalcon application? When setting DI with services is not working, how to handle that application?

```
    use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
    use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault; 
    use Commonapi\App\Library\ApiServices as ApiServices;
    class Bootstrap
    {
     public function run($opt){
     $app = new Micro();
     foreach ($loaders as $service) {
         $function = 'init' . ucfirst($service);
         $this->{$function}($app);
     }
     $services = new ApiServices($this->di);
     $app->setDI($services->di);
     return $app->handle();
 }

//have loaded config,routes,loader by separate functions
```

Answer (score -1):

Why exactly pass `$app` to `$function` ? What is not working ? Any error or something ? Maybe do something like:

```
foreach ($loaders as $service) {
    $function = 'init' . ucfirst($service);
    $this->{$function}();
}
$services = new ApiServices($this->di);
$app = new Micro($services->di);
return $app->handle();
```

also what exactly is `ApiServices` ?

Comment: in micro phalcon routing needs to be pass controller object inorder to mount  micro object..for that app is passed.

Comment: $this->di['curl'] = function(){
            return new Curl();
        };

Comment: i createed di for classes inside api services

Comment: micro object must created before the loaders as it is needed to pass to the routes

Comment: Why you need pass it to routes ? Where this is in docs ? You don't need $app in controller. Controller extends injectable so you can access any service in it.

OH right you mean `$app->mount`, okay, but what is not working with current setup ?

Also where you define `$loaders`

Comment: nedd to set up app->setDi($services->di),bt when using this it returns nothing.But when using without injecting app->setDi($services->di) its working good

Comment: What you mean it returns nothing ? im using $app->setDi and it owrks for me without any problem.

Comment: it shows 200 .bt no output is shown if i assign $services = new ApiServices($this->di);
        $app->setDi($services->di);
        $app->handle();

Comment: $services = new ApiServices($this->di);
$app->handle();

Comment: bt output ll come fa above

Comment: but output  is coming for the below

Comment: $services = new ApiServices($this->di);
$app->handle();